# How to I add a current timestamp (extra column) in the glue job so that the output data has an extra column

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, etl, aws-glue

How to I add a current timestamp (extra column) in the glue job so that the output data has an extra column. In this case:

Schema Source Table:
Col1, Col2

After Glue job.

Schema of Destination:
Col1, Col2, Update_Date(Current Timestamp)

Answer (score 15):

We do the following and works great without converting toDF()

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(...)

from datetime import datetime
def AddProcessedTime(r):
    r["jobProcessedDateTime"] = datetime.today() #timestamp of when we ran this.
    return r

mapped_dyF = Map.apply(frame = datasource0, f = AddProcessedTime)
```

Comment: This works, but could you explain what is going on here? What is `r`? Looks like a parameter defined in the AddProcessedTime function, but then you don't pass it as an argument when you define `f = AddProcessedTime`?

Comment: @gbeaven R is the dynamic frame

Comment: in `AddProcessTIme`, `r` is `DynamicRecord` object https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-map.html

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure if there's a glue native way to do this with the `DynamicFrame`, but you can easily convert to a Spark Dataframe and then use the `withColumn` method. You will need to use the `lit` function to put literal values into a new column, as below.

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

glue_df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(...)
spark_df = glue_df.toDF()
spark_df = spark_df.withColumn('some_date', lit(datetime.now()))
```

Some references:

- [Glue DynamicFrame toDF()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-toDF)
- [Spark Dataframe withColumn()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn)

Comment: `from datetime import datetime` statement is missing in above code snippet

Answer (score 2):

In my experience working with Glue the timezone where Glue runs is GMT. But my timezone is CDT. So, to get CDT timezone I need to convert the time within SparkContext. This specific case is to add last_load_date to the target/sink.

So I created a function.

```
def convert_timezone(sc):
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
local_time=dt.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
local_time_df=sqlContext.createDataFrame([(local_time,)],['time'])
CDT_time_df = local_time_df.select(from_utc_timestamp(local_time_df['time'],'CST6CDT').alias('cdt_time'))
CDT_time=[i['cdt_time'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for i in CDT_time_df.collect()][0]
return CDT_time
```

And then call the function like ...

```
job_run_time =  date_config.convert_timezone(sc)

datasourceDF0 = datasource0.toDF()
datasourceDF1 = datasourceDF0.withColumn('last_updated_date',lit(job_run_time))
```

Answer (score 2):

As I have been seen there is not a properly answer to this issue I will try to explain my solution to this problem:

First thing is to clarify the `withColumn` function is a good way to do this but it is important to mention that this function is from the `Dataframe` from Spark itself and this function is not part of the glue DynamicFrame which is a own library from Glue AWS, so you need to covert the frames to do this....

First step is from the `DynamicFrame` get the Spark `Dataframe`, glue library does this with the function toDF() function, once with the Spark frame you can add the column and/or do whatever manipulation you require.

Then what we glue expect is his own frame so we need to transformed back from spark to glue proprietary frame, to do so you can use the apply function of the DynamicFrame, which requires to import the object:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame
```

and use the glueContext which you should already have it, like:

```
DynamicFrame(sparkDataFrame, glueContext)
```

In resume the code should looks like:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import com.amazonaws.services.glue.DynamicFrame

...

val sparkDataFrame = datasourceToModify.toDF().withColumn("created_date", current_date())
val finalDataFrameForGlue = DynamicFrame(sparkDataFrame, glueContext)

...
```

Note: the `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` is to bring the `current_date()` function to add the column with the date.

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 1):

Use Spark's [`current_timestamp()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#current_timestamp) function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

...

val timestampedDf = source.toDF().withColumn("Update_Date", current_timestamp())
val timestamped = DynamicFrame(timestampedDf, glueContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this supposedly with a built-in functionality now: see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context-add-ingestion-time-columns)...

Note to look for just the `glueContext.add_ingestion_time_columns` section